# How to create/find a dereverberation filter?

Tags: matlab, filters, discrete-signals, filter-design

I want to find the coefficients of dereverberation filter in MATLAB. How to do that?
I have found the coefficients of reverberation filter:

```
numerator  = b = [0.1664 0 0.4084 0 0.3341 0 0.0911]
denominator = a = [1 0 0 0 0 0 0]
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_forcing_equalizer

Comment: Dereverberation requires a lot more than just linear filtering.

Comment: To get the simplest inverse filter, just swap the numerators and the denominators. However, as Hilmar says, dereverberation is a complex topic and requires a lot.

Comment: @ZRHan So I found the dereverberation coefficients but when I filter the reverbed signal through these numerator and denominator which are:
b_dereverb = [4.6297 0 0 0 0 0 0];
a_dereverb = [1 0 2 0 1,3333 0 4];
I don't get the expentantly results. Why that?

Comment: I dunno why you didn't get the expected results. I'm using the following codes and get a perfect results: `b = [0.1664 0 0.4084 0 0.3341 0 0.0911]; a = [1 0 0 0 0 0 0];  x = a;  y = filter(b, a, x); xx = filter(a, b, y);`